# openni_camera operation mode 7

Tags: openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,

I am fooling around with the operation mode parameters for rgb and depth images on the [openni_camera driver](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera#openni_camera.2BAC8-electric.ROS_API)

When I set *image_mode* and *depth_mode* to 8 (160x120 @ 30FPS) everything works OK, but if I set mode 7 (160x120 @ 25FPS) the following warning pops out:

```
[ WARN] [1350026804.389463555]: Could not find any compatible image output mode for 160 x 120 @ 25. Falling back to default image output mode 640 x 480 @ 30.
[ WARN] [1350026804.389502213]: Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 160 x 120 @ 25. Falling back to default depth output mode 640 x 480 @ 30.
```

Is mode 7 (160x120 @ 25FPS) not really present on Kinect? Or is there any other reason for this behavior?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45673/openni_camera-operation-mode-7/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mode 7 (160x120 @ 25FPS) is just not present on Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1